# Accessing function-definition-time, not evaluation-time, value for a variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I hope that I can do something like this, and the output would be "hello"

```
#!/bin/bash

foo="hello"

dummy() {
  local local_foo=`echo $foo`
  echo $local_foo
}

foo=''

dummy
```

---

This question means that I would like to capture the value of some global values at definition time, usually used via `source blablabla.bash` and would like that it defines a function that captures current variable's value.

Comment: Since you intentionally do  `foo=''` before calling the dummy function, you pretty much cannot.

Comment: Also, typically you would use `local_foo="$foo"` instead of `echo`ing and capturing the result.  If you're new to bash, I would recommend [this bash guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).

Comment: ...so you want to capture the value of a variable **at function definition time**, not at evaluation time? Consider editing your question to be specific that that's what you want (and no, you can't do it without creating a separate variable).

Comment: ...well, creating a separate variable, or doing something *really* awful (dynamically generating your function).

Comment: BTW, what's your real goal here? Hopefully you aren't, say, intending to hide a password from the user by clearing it from the set of locals -- given how trivial it is to access raw text for a function, such an action would be of effectively no use.

Comment: Real goal is function generation. If not available, I'd have to, write something using some other language, generate a bash file, and load it up to have a wide variety of different stuffs for me.

Comment: "Function generation" is not an end, but a means to an end. Without knowing the actual end (be that data-hiding or something else), it's impossible to evaluate suitability of a given approach.

Comment: ...that said, yes, it's possible, but to do it *safely* requires bash's `printf '%q'` builtin (as used in the "Insane Way" section of my answer) or some equivalent. You need to be careful on that, too -- I've seen implementations (in Java, for instance) that were exploitably buggy, able to evaluate maliciously-formed data as code.

Comment: I need to define some functions, which are quite similar. Well, best way to do it would be using `macro`, but bash definitely has not it.

Comment: `local local_foo=$foo` is dangerously buggy: If your `foo` value contains an expansion such as `$(rm -rf $HOME)`, it'll be executed, whereas the `printf '%q'` approach I showed in my answer doesn't have that vulnerability. If you want to add an answer, it should be added *as an answer*, so it can get upvotes/downvotes/comments separate from the question itself, rather than having "privileged status" as part of the question.

Comment: See for example [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) on meta; likewise [Editing self-answer out of question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278050/editing-self-answer-out-of-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Sane Way

Functions are evaluated when they're run, not when they're defined. Since you want to capture a variable as it exists at definition time, you'll need a separate variable assigned at that time.

```
foo="hello"

# By convention, global variables prefixed by a function name and double underscore are for
# the exclusive use of that function.
readonly dummy__foo="$foo" # capture foo as of dummy definition time, and prevent changes
dummy() {
  local local_foo=$dummy__foo # ...and refer to that captured copy
  echo "$local_foo"
}

foo=""
dummy
```

---

#### The Insane Way

If you're willing to commit crimes against humanity, however, it *is* possible to do code generation to capture a value. For instance:

```
# usage: with_locals functionname k1=v1 [k2=v2 [...]]
with_locals() {
  local func_name func_text assignments

  func_name=$1; shift || return ## fail if out of arguments
  (( $# )) || return            ## noop if not given at least one assignment

  func_text=$(declare -f "$func_name")

  for arg; do
    if [[ $arg = *=* ]]; then   ## if we already look like an assignment, leave be
      printf -v arg_q 'local %q; ' "$arg"
    else                        ## otherwise, assume we're a bare name and run a lookup
      printf -v arg_q 'local %q=%q; ' "$arg" "${!arg}"
    fi
    assignments+="$arg_q"
  done
  # suffix first instance of { in the function definition with our assignments
  eval "${func_text/{/{ $assignments}"
}
```

...thereafter:

```
foo=hello

dummy() {
  local local_foo="$foo"
  echo "$local_foo"
}
with_locals dummy foo ## redefine dummy to always use the current value of "foo"

foo=''
dummy
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can comment out or remove the `foo=''` line, and that will do it.  The function `dummy` does not execute until you call it, which is after you've blanked out the `foo` value, so it makes sense that you would get a blank line echoed.  Hope this helps.

Comment: It's hard to believe that this is telling the OP anything they don't already know -- why would they have put `foo=''` in there, if not to illustrate their intent to use the value as it existed when `dummy` was defined, vs the value as it exists when `dummy` is run?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to execute the code inside a function unless that function gets called by bash. There is only an alternative of calling some other function that is used to define the function you want to call after.
That is what a dynamic function definition is.

I don't believe that you want that.

An alternative is to store the value of foo (calling the function) and then calling it again after the value has changed. Something hack-sh like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo="hello"

dummy() {
    ${global_foo+false} && 
        global_foo="$foo" || 
            echo "old_foo=$global_foo new_foo=$foo" 
}
dummy

foo='new'
dummy

foo="a whole new foo"
dummy
```

Calling it will print:

```
$ ./script
old_foo=hello new_foo=new
old_foo=hello new_foo=a whole new foo
```

As I am not sure this address your real problem, just: Hope this helps.

Comment: Naming a global variable with a `local_` prefix is a bit misleading, no? (And if the OP wanted to copy content to a different global variable, I'd argue that there are... less-surprising... ways to do that than having the first invocation of a function have an entirely different behavior than future invocations inside the same shell or its subshells).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sure, let me put a note about the global_variable. And, yes, that's why I called the solution "hackish" from the start.

Answer (score 0):

After inspired by @CharlesDuffy, I think using eval might solve some of the problems, and the example can be modified as following:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo="hello"

eval "
dummy() {
  local local_foo=$foo
  echo \$local_foo
}
"

foo=''

dummy
```

Which will give the result 'hello' instead of nothing.

---

@CharlesDuffy pointed out that such solution is quite dangerous:

> local local_foo=$foo is dangerously buggy: If your foo value contains
>   an expansion such as $(rm -rf $HOME), it'll be executed

Using eval is good in performance, however being bad in security. And therefore I'd suggest @CharlesDuffy 's answer.

Comment: You *can* modify this to be safer: If you run `printf -v foo_q '%q' "$foo"`, and then use `$foo_q` inside your `eval`, then it won't be exploitable as-described. You could also use `$(printf '%q' "$foo")` when generating the text to `eval`, but this comes at a performance penalty since it creates a subshell unless your interpreter is (like ksh93) smart enough to optimize it out.

Comment: (of course, my own answer pays the subshell penalty once, too, to capture the output of `declare -f` -- I presume that's what you're referring to when you talk about a hand-written `eval` being faster; on modern unixlikes subshells are relatively cheap, but there certainly are platforms where bash runs -- such as Cygwin -- where they're more expensive).